# How to read file from storage in Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I made a DRM media player app in Xamarin which drops course.licns and pass.licns files in internal memory in app directory for reading correct key.

It's working fine in Android 10 but it's not working in above versions like Android 11 and 12 when I put course name and key then app added both files but can't read it again when I want to play a video. The same thing is working fine on lower versions.

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Android.OS;

namespace MediaElement
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Add : ContentPage
    {
        public Add()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        async void Appears(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.FindByName<Entry>("ID").Text =Helper. GetIMEI();
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error!", e2.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }
        public static string Pass()
        {
            return Path.Combine((string)System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "pass.licns");

            //return Path.Combine((string)System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "pass.licns");

        }

        public static string Course()
        {

            //return Path.Combine((string)System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "course.licns");
            return Path.Combine((string)System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "course.licns");
        }

    void Register(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string key = this.FindByName<Entry>("Key").Text.Trim();
                string Name = this.FindByName<Entry>("Name").Text.Trim();


                if (key== string.Empty || Name == string.Empty) { throw new Exception("Key or Name is empty"); }
                if (!IsBase(key)) { throw new Exception("Invalid key!"); }
                if (!IsValidID(key)) { throw new Exception("This key is not designed for your ID."); }


                if (File.Exists(Pass()) && File.Exists(Course()))
                {
                    if (File.ReadAllText(Pass()).Contains(key) || File.ReadAllText(Course()).Contains(Name)){ throw new Exception("Key or Course Already exists."); }
                }

                File.AppendAllText(Pass(), key+",");
                File.AppendAllText(Course(), Name + ",");
                DisplayAlert("Success", "License added successfully.", "Ok");
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", e2.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }

        bool IsBase(string base64)
        {
            try
            {
                if (base64 == Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.FromBase64String(base64))) { return true; }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               
            }
            return false;
        }

   public static bool IsValidID(string key)
        {
                   return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MainPage.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(key),Helper. IDkey)).Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].ToString() == Helper. GetIMEI();
        }

    }

}
```

**Note:**

I don't want to use All file access permissions due to so many restrictions in Google Play Store and my App is only accessing a particular file. Is there a proper way for upper versions?

Comment: the code you posted just builds the paths, where is the code that is actually doing the read/write and failing?  And how exactly does it fail - is there an error or exception?

Comment: it throw a error  in androdi11 and 12

if (!IsBase(key)) { throw new Exception("Invalid key!"); }

Comment: YOUR code is throwing an exception.  That does not provide enough context to actually demonstrate the problem.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? This question is difficult to understand. I would also recommend using the Xamarin.Essentials Filesystem Helpers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android

Comment: @Jason i edited the question can you please answer this now?

Comment: @ewerspej can you please check it now.

Comment: What exception do you receive? Did you put breakpoints in your code already to see what might be going wrong? For example, what happens if you simply assign the path to a variable like so: `var path = Pass();`, does `path` hold a valid file path or does it throw? I still recommended using Xamarin.Essentials for this

Comment: According to your earlier comment it is failing when decoding the key value?  This happens before it attempts to read the file.

Comment: @ewerspej i receive message (Invalid Key) but when i add course name and key then app accept that and throw a message (License added successfully) but when i want to play a video then throw that message invalid key but the same thing and same build is working fine in other lower versions of Android like 10 9 8.

Comment: @Jason im not sure what is the exact error here because same build is working fine in other android versions but in Android 11 12  throw ( Invalid Key ) message whenever i try to play a encrypted video but when i add course name and key then app that accept Throw a message License added successfully but throwing error while reading video file.

Comment: the only way to fix this is to first step through the code in the debugger and determine exactly where the problem is occurring.

Comment: We need to see the exception. Can you add the debug console output with the stack trace of the exception to the question (as text) and also let us know in which line this occurs in your sample code?